# Creating a Yii webapp without command line?

Tags: php, yii

To install the Yii Framework, after unpack the file the tutorial always told me to enter text in command line like this : -

```
yiic webapp testing01
```

Is there anyway to do it not by the command line ?

---

Edit :

I wonder why this is off-topic.

ok, here is something for refence  :

In the book "[Agile Web Application Development with Yii1.1 and PHP5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849518726)" (by Jeffrey Winesett) in Chapter 2: Getting Started. Page 23.

> To create a new application, we are going to use a little powerhouse of a tool known as yiic that comes packaged with the framework. This is a command-line tool that one can use to quickly jumpstart a brand new Yii application. It is not mandatory to use this tool, but it saves a lot of time and guarantees that the proper folder and file structure is in place.

It said "It is not mandatory to use this tool", which means there is some way to create a yii webapp without yiic (which is the command line way I mention).

so here my question again : How to Creating a Yii webapp without using the 'command line' tool, yiic ?

Comment: Please do not flag this as a SuperUser question. It is not!

Comment: if you are asking is there some other web GUI interface that creates a template for you then no, if you are asking whether this is mandatory then yes you can. You can create your own application architecture, folder and file structure, and boilerplate code, and just include Yii autoloader in your entry script. Also there are some non default templates for specific purposes(yii+backbone, YiiBoilerplate etc) you can download from github and setup without running yiic

Answer (score 0):

You can use some IDE.
For example Netbeans. There is Yii plugin installed there(if not installed, then install it). Simply creat new Project step by step. At the end there would be "select framework" option. chouse Yii framework. if everything is ok with settings of PHP it will install yii automatically. (It may ask base yii file, if so you can point to yiic.php)